# MySQL Query tables in many to many relationship

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I'm having trouble creating a SQL query. I have prepared 3 tables with few records:

tbl_documents

```html
+-------------+------------------+
| document_id | document_type_id |
+-------------+------------------+
|        0001 | PRE              |
|        0002 | PRE              |
|        0003 | PRE              |
+-------------+------------------+
```

tbl_users

```html
+---------+------------------+
| user_id |    user_name     |
+---------+------------------+
| Jara-PC | Jara S           |
| User1   | Uživatel 1       |
| User2   | Uživatel 2       |
+---------+------------------+
```

Each document can have multiple approvers (users) and each user can be approver for multiple documents, so i created many to many reletionship using table tbl_approvers

tbl_approvers

```html
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
| approver_id | document_id | document_type_id |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
| Jara-PC     |        0001 | PRE              |
| Jara-PC     |        0003 | PRE              |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
```

I have a problem with creating query **with this result** - For each document list a user who is not approver, like this:

```html
+------------------+-------------+--------------+
| document_type_id | document_id | not_approver |
+------------------+-------------+--------------+
| PRE              |           1 | User1        |
| PRE              |           1 | User2        |
| PRE              |           2 | Jara-PC      |
| PRE              |           2 | User1        |
| PRE              |           2 | User2        |
| PRE              |           3 | User1        |
| PRE              |           3 | User2        |
+------------------+-------------+--------------+
```

I created query, which will return approver for each document:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT tdoc.document_type_id,
           tdoc.document_id,
           ta.approver_id
    FROM tbl_documents tdoc
    LEFT JOIN tbl_approvers ta
        ON tdoc.document_id = ta.document_id AND
           tdoc.document_type_id = ta.document_type_id) tc;
```

Result:

```html
+------------------+-------------+----------+
| document_type_id | document_id | approver |
+------------------+-------------+----------+
| PRE              |        0001 | Jara-PC  |
| PRE              |        0002 | null     |
| PRE              |        0003 | Jara-PC  |
+------------------+-------------+----------+
```

Now I am stuck, I can make a query to check if there is a user who does not approve any document, but that is not what i want. Can it be even done in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
    Select u.userid as "Not Approver" ,  
    d.* from
     tbl_users u left join
    tbl_approvers a on
     u.userid <a.approver_id
     right join
     tbl_documents d
      On 
     a.document_id =d.document_id 
     and a.document_type_id  = d. 
      document_type_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @Himanshu AhujA answer I was able to do what i want:
When i used query, I get good result for documents which have at least one approver, for documents without any record in tbl_approver table I get null in a Not Approver column so i change it like this:

```
Select u.user_id as "Not Approver" ,
    d.*
from tbl_users u
left join tbl_approvers a
    on u.user_id > a.approver_id
RIGHT join tbl_documents d
    On a.document_id = d.document_id and
       a.document_type_id  = d.document_type_id
WHERE u.user_id is not null
union
Select f.user_id as "Not Approver" ,
    d.*
from tbl_users u
left join tbl_approvers a
    on u.user_id > a.approver_id
RIGHT join tbl_documents d
    On a.document_id = d.document_id and
       a.document_type_id  = d.document_type_id
join tbl_users f on u.user_id is null;
```

And now i have wanted result:

```html
+--------------+-------------+------------------+
| Not Approver | document_id | document_type_id |
+--------------+-------------+------------------+
| User1        |        0001 | PRE              |
| User2        |        0001 | PRE              |
| Jara-PC      |        0002 | PRE              |
| User1        |        0002 | PRE              |
| User2        |        0002 | PRE              |
| User1        |        0003 | PRE              |
| User2        |        0003 | PRE              |
+--------------+-------------+------------------+
```